# Xamarin forms FlexLayout select control using C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms application for Android TV, I want to select component (Card) inside Flex layout using backend code, so that users can navigate using remote. There is option for selecting item for listview. I can't find same functionality for Flexlayout. Seeking help from experts.

Comment: use a gesture recognizer

Comment: gesture recogniser can be used for handling touch/click events. I have already done it. I want to select an item using backend code. Xamarin Android have this

`MListView.SetSelection(0);`

Comment: a FlexLayout does not have any concept of "selected" like a ListView does

Comment: So, any alternate control in Xamarin.Forms for arrange components (Cards) responsively ?

Comment: @anishpsla About selecting item from FlexLayout, you may need to use gesture recognizer to get, one similar thread :[Xamarin MVVM Select Item From A Bindable FlexLayout Similar To Selecting Item On ListView](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179543/xamarin-mvvm-select-item-from-a-bindable-flexlayout-similar-to-selecting-item-on-listview)